# extend WebApplication or extend SpringWebApplication Difference

Tags: java, wicket

This is my question. I search Internet but no luck.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Where it is from? Context is missing. Are you referring to classes with these names in your project?

Comment: @sudmong, I am tacking about org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication and org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplication. I tagged my question by wicket, then obviously I would not refer to some classes of my project. Isn't it :)

Comment: A tag does not make for an obvious source. Some people will pick up on your intent, others will not. You should be as thorough as possible writing your question, providing links as you can, show us the legwork you've already done. That way if and when someone finds your question in the future, it and answers might help them too.

Comment: don't expect someone to elaborate a proper answer, if you don't want to take the time to write a proper question

Comment: The answer of ach_i was accepted so is there any need to vote down this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used [Apache Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/), but a quick look at the [SpringWebApplication javadoc](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/spring/SpringWebApplication.html) would tell you that if you are on java 5, you should not extend that class, rather extend WebApplication and use annotations to do your injection. (The Deprecation notice).

Comment: And regardless, SpringWebApplication extends WebApplication already.  So, you'd probably extend SpringWebApplication.